# How to query a cell reference that contains '

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to run a where query using a cell reference. The reference cell contains B1 with an ' in it. The result is always `#N/A`

I've tried several different versions of queries with contains and like.

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(B2, "Sheet1!A1:G1100"), 
 "select Col3 where Col4 = '"&A106&"'", 0),"")
```

I would like to get the contents of A1 and instead I'm getting `#N/A`

Comment: You have a missing `}`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(B2, "Sheet1!A1:G1100")}, 
 "select Col3 where Col4 contains '"&A106&"'", 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after some more trial and error. I removed the ' and used the contains function.